# Regex Js Replace Img Attributes

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var str = '<img data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" class="emoticon-speechless" src="img/emoji/emoticon-speechless.gif" title=":)"> text content<br> <img data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" class="emoticon-speechless" src="img/emoji/emoticon-sad.gif" title=":(">';
```

Regex replace img remove and use title attr

```
:) text content <br> :(
```

how can I get replace str var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following regex

```
/<img.*title="(.*)">/i
```

Complete snippet:

```js
var str = '<img data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" class="emoticon-speechless" src="img/emoji/emoticon-speechless.gif" title=":)"> text content<br>';
console.log(str.replace(/<img.*title="(.*)">/i,'$1'));
```

Comment: so there are few icons, please re answer replace all value

Comment: i need replace_all in the text

Comment: Ohhh what do you want to me update??? What you want to replace. i saw your updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using regex to do this? It sounds like may be this is an [X/Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/), that is, is there some task you're trying to achieve that you *think* regex is the solution to?

I'd be looking at doing this with `replaceChild` to change the img nodes into something you actually want.

```js
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("img")).forEach(function(img) {
  img.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(img.title), img);
})
```

```html
<img data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" class="emoticon-speechless" src="img/emoji/emoticon-speechless.gif" title=":)"> text content<br> <img data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" class="emoticon-speechless" src="img/emoji/emoticon-sad.gif" title=":("></div>
```

If you really have a string you're needing to manipulate:

```js
var str='<img data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" class="emoticon-speechless" src="img/emoji/emoticon-speechless.gif" title=":)"> text content<br> <img data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" class="emoticon-speechless" src="img/emoji/emoticon-sad.gif" title=":(">'

var container = document.createElement("div");
container.innerHTML = str;

Array.prototype.slice.call(container.querySelectorAll("img")).forEach(function(img) {
  img.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(img.title), img);
})

var outstr = container.innerHTML;

document.body.innerHTML = outstr;
```